# What is lk partition

Tags: lg, partitions

I have a LG phone (K350nds) which bootloader can be unlocked but no recovery can be flashed or kernel because of some signature or whatever, on similar model (K10) that can be bypassed by modifying aboot partition to make some function always return true but that is qualcomm device on same place on my phone (MTK mt6735) there is partition called lk. So what is that partition and what is her purpose?

Comment: What's its size? Could you dump it with `dd`?

Comment: @Death Mask Salesman I found that is called little kernel partition and can be found on mediatek devices but I don't know it's purpose. I have .bin file from stock rom it's size is 512 kb, I can't dd because I'm not rooted.

Comment: It handles driver configurations for the LCM ( Display Driver ) and other configurations, i flash it to fix GPU errors on ported roms